# type qualifier without type specifier

Tags: c

In the ISO/IEC 9899:1999, in §6.7.7 **Type definitions**, the 3rd example (the 6th paragraph marked on the border) is incorrect.  The explanation from the example is so (see the code in the bottom):

> The first two bit-field declarations differ in that unsigned is a
>   type specifier (which forces `t` to be the name of a structure member),
>   while **`const` is a type qualifier** (***which modifies `t` which is
>   still visible as a typedef name***).

It states that a declaration `const t:5` will make constant a previous definition of the type name `t`.  If we test this using gcc we see that we can mutate such a variable, so gcc ignores `const t`.  The same happens with with a compilation with clang.

I understand that it is possible to exist variables defined/declared via type qualifiers without type specifiers, which was contrary to my belief that a qualifier was only an attribute of a node keeping a type specifier, etc.

Where is the ambiguity in the C99?

```
typedef signed int t;
typedef int plain;
struct tag {
  unsigned t:4;
  const t:5;
  plain r:5;
};

int
main()
{
  t x;
  x = 10;
  return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, a function like the next one also compiles:

```
int
main()
{
  struct tag x = {.t = 3};
  x.t = 4;
  return 0;
}
```

**REMARK**:

I used clang and gcc.

**DOCUMENTS**:

Page 138, §6.7.8 from this edition

ISO/IEC 9899:201x  Committee Draft — April 12, 2011  N1570

**OR**

Page 124, §6.7.7 from this edition

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3  Committee Draft — September 7, 2007  WG14/N1256

Comment: it's not redefining the type definition, it's modifying the type as used for that specific variable where you added the qualifier.

Comment: It seems that .t can be modified, see the updated function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete spiel for the example (from ISO/IEC 9899:2011) is:

> EXAMPLE 3 The following obscure constructions
>
> ```
> typedef signed int t;
> typedef int plain;
> struct tag {
>     unsigned t:4;
>     const t:5;
>     plain r:5;
> };
> ```
>
> declare a typedef name `t` with type `signed int`, a typedef name `plain` with type `int`, and a structure
>   with three bit-field members, one named `t` that contains values in the range [0, 15], an unnamed const-qualified
>   bit-field which (if it could be accessed) would contain values in either the range [−15, +15] or
>   [−16, +15], and one named `r` that contains values in one of the ranges [0, 31], [−15, +15], or [−16, +15].
>   (The choice of range is implementation-defined.) The first two bit-field declarations differ in that
>   `unsigned` is a type specifier (which forces `t` to be the name of a structure member), while `const` is a
>   type qualifier (which modifies `t` which is still visible as a typedef name). If these declarations are followed
>   in an inner scope by
>
> ```
> t f(t (t));
> long t;
> ```
>
> then a function `f` is declared with type ‘‘function returning `signed int` with one unnamed parameter
>   with type pointer to function returning `signed int` with one unnamed parameter with type `signed int`’’, and an identifier `t` with type `long int`.

Note that the field identified by `const t:5;` is anonymous and therefore cannot be accessed (the standard mentions that with the 'if it could be accessed' comment, and the statement that it is an 'unnamed const-qualified bit-field').  The field named `t` is not const-qualified; it can be modified.

And the `const` field is part of the structure `struct tag` and does not affect anything outside that structure type.

Both your example programs should compile — it is just as well that GCC and Clang do compile them.

Note, too, that the example is marked 'obscure constructions'.  Anyone actually writing code like that for production should be … shunned until they repent of their evil ways.

Comment: Now I see . It is valid in fact.  Because in the first case `unsigned t:4` the type specifier is `unsigned` and `t` is an ID in the namespace of the members of struct, while in the 2nd case t is a type name in the namespace of identifiers, so they are entities in different pools, do not clash each other.  On the other hand ``const t:4`` is valid as an unnamed field as the type name `t` is an integer.  OK. Now it's clear.

Comment: Yes; that's the correct analysis.  It is the standard illustrating how excruciating some of the rules are.

Comment: Briefly, it is a type qualifier together with a type name instead of a type specifier in an obfuscated context.